# Why are electric charge, color charge referred to "quantum numbers"?

Tags: charge, gauge-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, color-charge

Quantum numbers characterizing a state are eigenvalues of operators. This is what we learn in quantum mechanics. But in quantum gauge theories, the electric charge, color charge, etc are also referred to as quantum numbers pertaining to a charged particle, a strongly interacting particle, etc. Why do we use the term "quantum number" for these properties even though they are not eigenvalues of any operator?

Comment: In reality, they *are* eigenvalues of operators, the operators coming from the conserved currents of Nöether's theorem.

Comment: @DavideMorgante Does Noether theorem apply to gauge symmetries?

Comment: @mithusengupta123 in general no, but often you can refer to the global part of the symmetry and talk about those quantum numbers.

Comment: Promoting a symmetry to a local one does not add any additional conserved current. As @FrodCube said, one understands quantum numbers as the ones associated to the global symmetry.

Answer (score 3):

For e.g. the complex scalar field, the conserved quantity which corresponds to *global* phase invariance, i.e. invariance under $\phi \mapsto e^{i\alpha}\phi \sim (1+i\alpha )\phi$ is given by

$$Q = \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{2\omega_p} (a^\dagger_p a_p - b^\dagger_p b_p)$$

which is simply the number of particles minus the number of antiparticles.  Multiplying this by the coupling constant $e$ yields the conservation of electric charge. If you have a state consisting of one particle and no antiparticles, then it is an eigenstate of $Q$ with eigenvalue $1$ (or $e$, if you multiply by the coupling constant).

Comment: Thanks, @J.Murray  Could you say something about the non-abelian gauge symmetry? Does color charge have such a simple expression?